# Download .jp2 type image in iOS swift

Tags: image, download, jpeg2000

How to download .jp2 type image from URL in iOS swift?I have tried with normal URL downlod session task. It’s download data from URL but data is not converted to UIImage type and set to an imageview. I also try with compressing By JPEGData but not working. Thanks in advance.

func downloadImageFromUrl() {
let newSession = URLSession.shared
let downloadTask = newSession.downloadTask(with: self.imageUrl) { (location, response, error) in
if let locationUrl = location, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: locationUrl) {

```
         let image = UIImage(data: data)
        
        self.downloadHandler?(image,self.imageUrl, self.indexPath,error)
      }
      self.finish(true)
      self.executing(false)
    }
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: Try to put some code, so that others can improve it or find errors.

Comment: func downloadImageFromUrl() {
        let newSession = URLSession.shared
       let downloadTask = newSession.downloadTask(with: self.imageUrl) { (location, response, error) in
        if let locationUrl = location, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: locationUrl) {
            
             let image = UIImage(data: data)
            
            self.downloadHandler?(image,self.imageUrl, self.indexPath,error)
          }
          self.finish(true)
          self.executing(false)
        }
        downloadTask.resume()
    }

Comment: This is my function to download image from URL. The type of URL i passed to this function is ".jp2". and Download image size is around 7.7 MB.